# SignalR connection between clients and users in my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am developing a mvc project and a windows service project about news. These are two different projects but they connect to same database. The windows service project is running on background and updates my database from different web services in every 10 minutes.

My mvc project have login page and news page like facebook. My database have users table, news table and news categories table. Every user should sign in and choose some news category and see news about this category like facebook page.

I want to add a realtime notification system in my project. When some news are added to my database by windows service project, I want to show these news to the online users in realtime because I do not want them to refresh page repeatly.

I did some research and find SignalR. When a new come to my database, I want to call my Hub in mvc project from windows service project and show this new to the user who chose the category.

Is there any problem about this?

The real problem is I can see the users in my hub by onconnected() method and signalr give them connectionId (like this "34de0f5d-f153-45cd-9e48-77fgr4t7gh4") but how can I know which of my user is this?
How can I make the releationship between my user table and signalr users?

Comment: This question is too broad and it would help if you include some code to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

When signalr start connection it create connectionid, so you can save connectionid of user in database and manage one flag(isOnline) for user online , hence if user is online flag is true and user is offline flag is false. now when you want to send notification to online users just check which user is online and get its connectionid from database and send notification.